# Does Azure Backup use GPv1 or GPv2 or Blob Storage account?

Tags: backup, azure, azure-storage

I'm guessing Azure Backup uses Blob Storage account rather than  General Purpose v1 accounts (GPv1) or  General Purpose v2 accounts (GPv2) and I'm looking for a confirmation of this in the Azure documentation. Please help

If I choose to keep a copy of the backup created by Azure Backup in Hot, Cool, Archive storage, what is the process to move it from Block Blob?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Backup Recovery Services Vault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-architecture#where-is-data-backed-up) is a different entity than a storage account. It is not Blob and does not have hot/cool/archive tiers. Restores to your choice of storage account are documented.

As of June 2019, Azure Backup can backup VM disks and Azure File shares. To backup Azure Blob, use a different solution.

Instead of vault, it is possible to implement your own backup by copying between storage accounts. See [this sample code for incremental and full Blob backups](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-block-blob-dotnet-backup), and [accompanying blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-block-blob-storage-backup/). Or perhaps buy backup software that does something similar if you don't want to build one.